# Flex SKD's main project and external SWC's

Tags: flex3, flex4, apache-flex

Can I have an application that is based on flex4 SDK and a library (swc file) inside this project which is based on another version of flex (3.2)?

how will flex deal with this situation?

Comment: afaik it should be compatible

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Think of it this way:

Your Flex application starts loading and flashPlayer loads in the UIComponent class.  When the classes from your swc are used (and they have a UIComponent compiled-in from Flex 3.2) flashPlayer uses the already-used UIComponent from the swf that was first initializing, not the one that was compiled into the swc.

[well, that's simplified -- it's the compiler that does all this crap to cut-down on swf size... modules do the same thing tho'. read up on applicationDomain stuff across modules -- if two modules use the same class and one is loaded first, the second (even if it has the updated version of that class) will use the old, first-loaded class.]

Best practice:  don't use swcs.  If possible, build from the source with the exact same sdk used for compiling.

Next-best practice:  Use swcs that don't use many Flex classes.  Swiz is a great example.... they pull in some flex classes, but if you search on the project for "mx." you'll find 25ish results of classes that won't change any time soon --- IMXMLObject, FlexEvent and some Binding classes.  If your swc uses ComboBox, you are in trouble, period. (have you seen bug releases for ComboBox in the last two years? -- that thing has changed more times since the 3.2sdk than the times I've changed clothes, and that's at least once per week).

I don't spend a lot of time on this site, but I'd be interested in knowing which swc you're trying to pull in.  Is it open-source?

I hope that helps.
Best of luck,
Jeremy

Comment: thanks. this is actually what my logic told me as well but I wanted a verification.

Comment: This answer is a bit inaccurate, I think.  The classes in a SWF are optimized at compile time, not at run time.  Although, one UIComponent may be compiled into the SWC, that same UIComponent will not be compiled into the SWF (Ignoring RSLs of the Flex Framework).  I strongly disagree on the recommendation that not using SWCs is a Best Practice, so -1 for that. They solve an important need despite version issues, and are the proper tool for reuse between projects.

Comment: re your comment: "at compile time, not run time."  Had you read my entire post, you would have seen that my way of addressing my inaccurate description was much cooler than yours, Jeff:  "it's the compiler that does all this crap to cut-down on swf size..."   If you're going to "strongly disagree", I'm going to guess that you've never had to fight with a Maven configuration with dozens of swcs compiled in.  As a developer, your goal should be to work an extra hour to set up the your projecst and you should NOT need to work for any longer than four minutes when changing your flex sdk version.

Comment: I'd rather NEVER have to do upgrade-support in the future by OWNING the source. We only pay $10,000+ for library projects that provide the source. If a provider will only give the swc, then he is making his clients work too hard and don't give a s*** about his clients.  Or maybe you've never had to support a project that had an old version of the AutoCompleteCombobox swc and had to spend over 30 minutes to bring in a swc that extended a class (mx.controls.form.ComboBox) that has changed dramatically in different versions of the sdk. Or maybe wasting 30+ minutes is acceptable to you?

Answer (score 0):

In theory, a Flex 3 SWC should work fine for all Flex 3 point releases.  A Flex 4 SWC should work fine with all Flex 4 point releases.  I wouldn't expect a Flex 3 SWC to work against Flex 4, but it depends what is in the SWC and what classes are used.

In practice, odd errors sometimes do crop up.  I strongly recommend compiling all your SWCs against the same SDK you use with your main project.  A lot of odd runtime and compiler errors can be solved by making sure your versions match.

This is the type of question that makes me wonder "wouldn't it have been quicker to try it than to ask the question." Are you having a specific problem?

Comment: I did, it broke, this is why my question touched on the theory of things. imagine you have legacy code (assume huge, and I do mean huge) that can only work with flex3 SDK. now, you have a project that needs to use this code as a library. can you compile the lib against flex3 and the project against flex4? sure... you can, that is known, the question is, behind the scenes, does the runtime "behave" the same with this combined project? and another thing, if you load the lib externally and not compiled within the project what then?